# Weird thing during installing a widget on Android

Tags: java, android, widget

I have totally weird problem on Android.

I have an app, which have also a widget (declared in manifest, etc).

Problem is, that sometimes when I debug an application (run it from android studio in debug mode) instead of my widget (with my icon, my name and my logic) something weird is installed - widget without title, with standard stock icon, and with one button inside "SYNC ALL CARDS".

I don't need to add that it doesn't work like my widget...

More weirdly, I don't have "SYNC ALL CARDS" string in whole project, I don't have any layout which could have such thing.

When I uninstall application and debug it again, it help.

What's going on? I can't upload such thing to android market.

Comment: Pls post your widget provider code.
Are you using a widget with collection, like listview?

Comment: Not, widget consist only imagebutton and imageview

Comment: Code is here

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/masterfixed/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/widgets/OnOffWidgetProvider.java

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/masterfixed/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/masterfixed/app/src/main/res/layout/wizard_informative.xml

Comment: as you can see, nothing suspiicious.

Comment: the first link with the javacode is broken. The layout and manifest file looks fine so far